# How can get data from html form and javascript array using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm sending a `HTML` form and `javascript` array using AJAX post method. But I can't get my data in the `PHP` file.

```
   $.post("addOrder.php", {
        "form": $("#placeOrderForm").serialize(),
        "array": array
    }, function(responce) {});
```

Comment: Can you please also include your php code to make sure it is correct on back-end side?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks. data is comming.. no error

Comment: @JavaEvgen My problem is how to get the data in back end.

Comment: Well, we need to see how the backend looks like before we can help you

Comment: @RAZERZ Front end => <form id="placeOrderForm"><input name="po"></form> Back end => $po = $_POST['form']['po'];
                   echo $po;

Comment: @RAZERZ  i want to get 'po'(input) data and array data in same php file.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Not even an error? var_dump the variable

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) clearly.

The update code:

```
$.post("addOrder.php",
  $("#placeOrderForm").serialize(),
  function(response) {
  }
);
```

And in `addOrder.php`, print the posted array using.

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
```

If you are using firebug, you will get the posted variables' array in response tab.

Answer (score 0):

// You can access the values posted by jQuery.ajax
// through the global variable $_POST, like this:

> $var = isset($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : null;

Comment: I think OP is having issues accessing this var

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like below:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "addOrder.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {<data1> : <val1>},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Looks like you passing argument is having issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addForm.php try this:

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

This will enable you to inspect the form data posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your php file:

```
 $params = array();
 echo parse_str($_POST, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I found my answer. I used "serializeArray" for sending form.

html

```
<form id="placeOrderForm">
    <input name="po">
    <input name="desc">
</form>
```

javascript

```
var array = [1,2];
$.post("addOrder.php",{
    "form":$("#placeOrderForm").serializeArray(), 
    "array":array
}, function (responce) {});
```

php

```
$form_input_data_1 = $_POST['form'][0]['value']; // get po's data
$form_input_data_2 = $_POST['form'][1]['value']; // get desc's data
$array_index_1_data = $_POST['array'][0]; // get 1
$array_index_2_data = $_POST['array'][1]; // get 2
```